# How to implement auto complete feature using Swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I want to implement auto complete feature like "Google" for example, I'm open for suggestions to use native controls or recommendations for third party controls.

I just want a text field that will take an array of strings and display suggestions according to what is written

I couldn't find cocoa pods controls for what i want in Swift 2.

I have tried this control: [Auto complete Cocoa pods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20on%3Aios%20autocomplete) but no luck its implemented in a way that does not fit my needs "He is depending on xib file" and also tried UISearchBar with Content. But couldnt find a proper tutorial for it on swift 2

Your support is highly appreciated

Comment: You should post what you already have in your question

Comment: Ok Edited my question

Comment: Restricting yourself to a pure Swift Solution is unnecessary, you can use 3rd party ObjC controls which are bridged natively to Swift.

Comment: @Darko Can i Add a text field on storyboard that is based on a "Objective C" Class?

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with objective-c, but you could see how is done here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat all UI elements are based on objective-c, so yes, you can

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat try this https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat please search something yourself there is many more classes and examples to implement AutoComplete Textfield.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA Tried this solution before didn't work because it is implemented in Swift 1.2, upgrading it is a hassle

Comment: @bazyl87 Thank you, ill try it

Comment: If you still not found than try bazyl87 link and try to create your custom autocomplete. Thank U!